# Getting infinity after operation on image data

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, onclick

I'm new to javascript, and now I'm learning to work with canvas. I wanted to make a simple check of how many times my image will fit in my canvas, but for some reason every time I run this script after refreshing the page, 'wbok' and 'wdol' are "infinity" - but it only happens once in Firefox, twice in a row in Chrome when I checked, every other time I run the script without refreshing (it's a function called by onclick) I get the proper result of the division.

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var myimg = new Image();
myimg.src = 'myimg.png';
var wbok = canvas.width / myimg.width;
var wdol = canvas.height / myimg.height;
console.log(wbok, wdol);
```

I suspect it's something to do with how the image is loaded on to canvas, but I can't figure out the specifics and how to fix it. I also tried putting onload function before and after setting image source:

```
myimg.onload = function() {
    c.drawImage(myimg, 0,0);
}
```

Still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
myimg.onload = function() {
    c.drawImage(myimg, 0,0);
}
```

This piece of code will draw the image on the canvas as soon as it has finished loading. But it's an asynchronous operation, and you're assigning a callback function to the image object's `onload` property, so this function will only be called after the load completes. This will not block the program, so it will immediately go towards the next line:

```
var wbok = canvas.width / myimg.width;
var wdol = canvas.height / myimg.height;
```

But the image may still be loading in the background, so the dimensions may be unknown, hence the infinity/infinity you see in the output. Instead you should query the canvas width and height after the image has finished loading, inside the callback function:

```
myimg.onload = function() {
    c.drawImage(myimg, 0,0);
    var wbok = canvas.width / myimg.width;
    var wdol = canvas.height / myimg.height;
    console.log(wbok, wdol);
}
```